# Why I can't add redshift to startup?

Tags: startup

recently, I have discovery [redshift](https://launchpad.net/redshift) (help your eyes hurt less if you are working in front of the screen at night)

I can run the tools using command line :
`redshift-gtk`

I run "startup manager" :
[image]

and I have add an entry :

[image]

And when I restart my computer, redshift does not start when I start my computer

Comment: use `gtk-redshift` instead of `redshift-gtk`.

Comment: When I type `gtk-redshift` in my terminal : the programm is not found

Comment: `redshift-gtk` requires at least Python 3.2 (since Redshift 1.9).
Before version 1.8 `redshift-gtk` was known as `gtk-redshift`.

Comment: The command should anyway be `redshift-gtk` (see the `Exec=` line in its desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`). Since it runs from command line, it should run as a startup application as well.

Comment: If I open : `redshift-gtk.desktop`, the Exec line look like : `Exec=redshift-gtk`

Comment: exactly, which means you should be able to run it by the command `redshift-gtk` in your startup applications. Silly thought, but could you try `/usr/bin/redshift`?

Comment: I have try, and it still does not work ... :( 
When I type : `pgrep redshift` : no result found

Comment: Can you check if Startup Applications creates a starter in `~/.config/autostart`?

Comment: yes, it is created, http://paste.ubuntu.com/8088986/

Comment: is the issue with redshift only? (btw, the command should indeed be redshift-gtk)

Comment: Yes it is only with redshift, other programs (like firefox or pidgin) work fine.
NB : What is the meaning of "bwt" ? (I'm not english native)

Comment: It's look like a bug. report it as a bug. [How do I report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: BTW is an acronym for By the Way, normally found in texting and chat.

Comment: also @Tim Guys, I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redshift/+bug/1188961 you can try the solution down on the page: install geoclue-hostip

Comment: @JacobVlijm , thank you, it's work fine now ! THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: perfect! would you mind if I made it an answer?

Comment: I just answer now but if you want point, post your answer , I will validate your answer and delete my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redshift/+bug/1188961), it is the result of a bug. However: as suggested on the page, you can try to install `geoclue-hostip`, which was a solution for at least some of the users.

```
sudo apt-get install geoclue-hostip
```

Note: `geoclue-hostip` *was* installed on my system, that could be the reason why I could not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a cron job.

Run the command:

```
crontab -e
```

Scroll to the bottom, and add this line

```
@reboot redshift-gtk
```

Then press enter (so you have a blank line below). That should now run at startup.

Comment: Hello, I have do this and when I reboot, `pgrep redshift` return nothing, it's don't work

Comment: It must be a problem with redshift. Try `/usr/bin/redshift` instead of `redshift`. Or use a different program - I use flux.

Comment: `/usr/bin/redshift` don't work too. I think I will do it but redshift is open source, not Flux

Comment: /usr/bin/redshift starts redshift without interface (see comments on the post)

Comment: Yes, but a process with `redshift` name must be created, right ?

Comment: As long as you have already set it up, even with no gui it should still work.

Comment: @Nymeria absolutely (I know because I killed it :)) and Tim: it should indeed. (it does here, and if I add it to startup applications, it works here as well)

Comment: This method worked for me, but additionally, I added redshift twice to the startup applications, just in case this doesn't work for anyone they could try this.

Answer (score 2):

I had plenty of issues trying to get `redshift-gtk` to autostart on my laptop (running Mint KDE 18). In the end I manged to get the right `systemd` configuration settings...

```
[Unit]
Description=Redshift display colour temperature adjustment
Documentation=http://jonls.dk/redshift/
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redshift-gtk -l 51.5:-0.1
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This should be saved as a user unit configuration file here:

`~/.config/systemd/user/redshift-gtk.service`

You can test the above by running:

```
systemctl --user start redshift-gtk
```

You should be able to see `redshift-gtk` working, or you can check that it is working by running:

```
systemctl --user status redshift-gtk
```

*NOTE: see the listing at the bottom for example output.*

Assuming the `redshift-gtk` service started correctly, you can set it to run automatically as part of the initial user login:

```
systemctl --user enable redshift-gtk
```

You can check that has worked correctly by running:

```
systemctl --user list-dependencies default.target
```

This should show something like the following (note the second line, directly below `default.target`):

```
default.target
● ├─redshift-gtk.service
● └─basic.target
●   ├─paths.target
●   ├─sockets.target
●   └─timers.target
```

Now when you restart you should see `redshift-gtk` working, but again you can check by running:

```
systemctl --user status redshift-gtk
```

Which should produce something like the following:

```
● redshift-gtk.service - Redshift display colour temperature adjustment
   Loaded: loaded (/home/robin/.config/systemd/user/redshift-gtk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-11-05 17:07:28 GMT; 47s ago
     Docs: http://jonls.dk/redshift/
 Main PID: 2074 (redshift-gtk)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/redshift-gtk.service
           └─2074 /usr/bin/redshift-gtk -l 51.5 -0.1

Nov 05 17:07:28 rksd-dev-01 systemd[1801]: redshift-gtk.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 05 17:07:28 rksd-dev-01 systemd[1801]: Stopped Redshift display colour temperature adjustment.
Nov 05 17:07:28 rksd-dev-01 systemd[1801]: Started Redshift display colour temperature adjustment.
```